# Render yesod widget

Tags: haskell, yesod

I follow the instructions [here](http://yannesposito.com/Scratch/en/blog/Yesod-tutorial-for-newbies/)

I create a yesod project, and render a widget with `defaultLayout`:

```
You've just posted
<p>#{postedText}#{T.reverse postedText}
<hr>
<p><a href=@{MirrorR}>Get back
```

And here is the default-layout.hamlet:

```
$maybe msg <- mmsg
    <div #message>#{msg}
^{widget}
<footer>
    #{extraCopyright $ appExtra $ settings master}
```

The problem is I expect only one link to MirrorR but I got two, one is `Get back`,the other is the copyright in `<footer>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write:

```
<p><a ...>...
```

Then, Hamlet sees a free `<p>` tag and creates a matching `</p>` tag around the following content. The content that follows is *assumed to be valid HTML*. What is rendered is thus:

```
<p><a ...>...</p>
```

What you instead want to write is either (note that the indentation creates a new free tag):

```
<p>
  <a ...>...
```

...or:

```
<p><a ...>...</a>
```

Your browser renders this as two links, because the `<a>` element isn't closed (and browsers go into quirks mode and enable HTML1 compatibility stuff in that case):

```
<p><a href="foo">link1</p>
<p>link2</p>
<!-- implicit </a> at the end of the closest block level element -->
```

Disclaimer: I don't have access to Yesod and can't verify this behavior; I only assume that it is like this based on the observations in the question.